# How can I parse a boolean expression to group it based on the conjunction?

Tags: algorithms, boolean-algebra

I have to design an algorithm to parse an array of terms and conjunctions into a grouped boolean expression. I never studied computer science and don't usually need this for web development, but today is different and I'm stumped.

I'm getting input like so:

```
a == 1 and b == 2 or c == 3 and d == 4
```

which I must turn into

```
(a == 1 and b == 2) or (c == 3 and d == 4)
```

it must also work with more complex expressionswith nested `or`s and `and`s:

```
a == 1 and b == 2 and c == 3 or d == 4 or e == 5 and f == 6...
```

which becomes

```
(a == 1 and b == 2 and c == 3) or (d == 4) or (e == 5 and f == 6)...
```

Is there a particular algorithm I could use to do this?

I'm using JavaScript if that makes a difference, and this is for an application where the user can enter a search with these terms which I must then translate into groups of terms that are using the same conjunctions (`or` and `and` only, there is no `not or` or `not and`).

so

```
a == 1 or b == 2 and c == 3
```

would become

```
// a == 1 or (b == 2 and c == 3)
[
  {
     group: {
       link: 'or',
       entries: [
         {
            term: 'a',
            operator: 'equal'
            value: '1'
         },
         {
           group: {
             link: 'and',
             entries: [
               {
                  term: 'b',
                  operator: 'equal'
                  value: '2'
               },
               {
                  term: 'c',
                  operator: 'equal'
                  value: '3'
               },
             ]
          }
       ]
    }
]
```

Something that confuses me very much is that `and` groups must be evaluated first, and then `or`ed together.

Any pointers as to how to approach this problem?

Comment: Just split the string using `or` as a separator, wrap each term in brackets and then concatenate them back? If `or` can appear inside terms (e.g. in a variable name or in string literal), perform lexical analysis first and, again, split using `or` token.

Comment: Parsing is a well-known area in computer science. In the olden days, you would either use a parser generator such as YACC/BISON (after tokenization, possibly using LEX/FLEX), or you would code up a recursive descent parser. In your case, I would look for a parsing library in JavaScript.

Comment: Your case is simple enough that you could use a recursive descent parser after tokenizing your input.

Comment: This page covers parsing in JavaScript: https://tomassetti.me/parsing-in-javascript/